# Cascading JFrames to open multiple Windows

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How many JFrames can be visible at a time simultaneously....?
I wrote a GUI program that opens another window when a button "Sign in" is clicked.That new window has its own button which opens another window.After the 3rd window no new window is opening.My program had maximum five windows.

Comment: It sounds like you may have answered your own question.  In my opinion, I think you've empirically proven that the answer is 5.

Comment: I would recommend having a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as much as JFrame you want .
There isn't any limitations as I know.
But if you are facing any tgere should be a solution.

You should just close current JFrame before opening other one.

Comment: setVisible(false) for the preceeding frame worked...thanks everyone

Comment: If it works then you should atleast
 thumbs up to the solution

Comment: *"You should just close current JFrame before opening other one."* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) *"you should atleast thumbs up to the solution"* The OP does not have enough rep. to upvote answers.